# Changing background using php's echo function

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to use

```
echo '<body style="background:url(img/backgroundloggedin.jpg) no-repeat";
               >';
```

In order to change the background image of my page but I'm finding no success doing so. The image won't fill 100% of the page regardless of what I am doing, I have tried `no repeat, fixed, 100%`

Comment: isn't `img/backgroundloggedin.jpg` supposed to be quoted?

Comment: Try -> `echo '<body style="background:url(\'img/backgroundloggedin.jpg\') no-repeat";` ??

Comment: It doesn't change a thing. More so, it makes it not be displayed at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple things wrong..  1) you need single quotes `'` in your `CSS` for image `url`.  Two the semicolon `;` needs to go IN the double quotes `"` for the `style` attribute.

IE

```
echo '<body style="background:url(\'img/backgroundloggedin.jpg\') no-repeat;">';
```

**NOTES**

That I `escaped` the single quote `'` with a `forward slash` as to not interfere with the `php` `echo` statment.

Now that the **syntax** is correct --  I suggest using a forward slash in front of `img` if your `img` directory is in web root.  --> IE `background:url(\'/img/backgroundloggedin.jpg\')`

Comment: Thanks! This has finally worked, is there any way i can display it on 100% of the page

Comment: add `background-size: cover`

Comment: This is what i have done but it leaves a blank white bar at the bottom. I will just end up using `background-color: black` and make the image dark towards the bottom. Thanks!

Comment: [URIs don't need to be wrapped in quotes inside `url(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/url#Syntax).